# How to refresh EKEventStore iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I write iOS application based on `EKEventStore`. I found strange flow:

My application is opened and I send new event from other Calendar (through gmail)

I have event listener:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
              selector:@selector(eventStoreChangedNotification:)
     name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification object:nil];
```

During  several minutes nothing happens. I don't see new event in my application. I think it because `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` not fired.

Ok, I press on Home button that moves my application to background and open *Default* iOS calendar.
Two seconds after, I see new event in *Default* Calendar. I close the Calendar and open my application again. From logs I see that  `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` immediately fired.

*Conclusions*

Somehow Default iOS Calendar *refreshed*  `EKEventStore`, suppose this action leads to trigger `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` on my application start.

How can I refresh `EKEventStore`?

I found only `refreshSourcesIfNecessary()`:

```
var _eventStore = EKEventStore()            
_eventStore.refreshSourcesIfNecessary()
```

If this is a way, do I need to run it once on App. start because I have several instances of `EKEventStore` over my project.

Thanks,

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ObservingChanges/ObservingChanges.html).  Compare the first code example to yours and note the difference.

Comment: @borrrden I know that I use `nil` instead `eventStore` instance but I found from other questions that I don't need to use this form

Comment: If you don't put in the instance of eventStore then how will the program know which event store's events you want?